# ActiveRecord has_one reference to an instance of the same class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-one

I have a class, `Page`. I want to call `page.next_page` or even `page.page` to get the next page.
When I create a new `Page` I want to associate assign the last page in my `Book` to have a `next_page` of the new `Page` I create.

```
class AddNextPageToPages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   add_column :pages, :page, :references
 end
end
```

This migration fails.

```

```
-- add_column(:pages, :next_page, {:class_name=>"Page"})
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `to_sym' for {:class_name=>"Page"}:Hash/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:395:in     `valid_alter_table_options'
```

```

Comment: try `add_reference :pages, :page`

Comment: undefined method add_reference

Answer (score -1):

You can read migration in rails http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/migrations.html to handle.

Comment: Please don't post link only answers. Explain how to do it.